# Application Will Terminate Notification & Saving Drafts (Core Data)

Tags: iphone, core-data

If the user is currently in my edit view controller, I want to be able to save the changes when the user closes my app. To do this I am observing the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` of the shared application. In my app delegate, I use the `applicationWillTerminate:` method to close things down and release all my core data contexts.

The problem I'm finding is that the `applicationWillTerminate:` method in the app delegate gets called *before* any observers react to the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification. This means that my core data stack has been released and closed before my edit view controller gets a chance to save anything!

How is this usually overcome because I can't see a way!

Many thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** *The first (notification-based) approach probably won't work due to the inner workings of run loops and notifications.*

If you want to stick with the notification-based architecture, you can actually post your own notifications from within `applicationWillTerminate:`. Simply create your own `MyApplicationWillTerminate` notification, then call `postNotification:` on `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`. Then have your edit controller register for instances of `MyApplicationWillTerminate` rather than the default `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`.

Another choice is to have your app delegate store an instance of your edit controller if it's visible, then in `applicationWillTerminate:` save the new info before releasing the Core Data context. This pollutes your app delegate with extra instance variables, though, so it may not be the optimal solution.

A last thought: why not have the app save whatever edits are being made as the user makes them? That way, you don't have to worry about the app closing halfway through editing a piece of info - the edits are already saved, and you can simply release the Core Data stuff as you already are. (This may not be appropriate for you; I really couldn't say without knowing more about your app structure and what data you're editing.)

Comment: +1 for saving drafts as the user makes their edits; time to do anything useful or complicated during termination is pretty limited.

Comment: Interesting point about saving edits as they happen. I might look into that. When you mention posting my own notifications, won't they get picked up on the next run loop and after the `applicationWillTerminate:` code has finished? As all the code will be on the same (main) thread.

Comment: Michael: you're probably right - I realized this right after I posted my answer (now edited). You're probably best off saving edits as they happen and thus sidestepping this problem altogether.

Comment: I've just had a thought! I noticed that the edit view controller's `viewWillDisappear:` method gets called before the `applicationWillTerminate:` does. So I could save my drafts then! It's not a very complicated save, just a plist with a few bits of data so I think it would be fine performing the save on terminate. Any thoughts or possible downsides?

Comment: You could, but remember that once the user presses the home button, Springboard gives your app a short period of time (around four or five seconds) to close itself or it will terminate the app for you. This looks like a frozen app and a crash to the user, which is not a good thing. Furthermore, even if you only take a second or two, you're giving the impression of a slowed-down device because of the delay between button push and home screen. So while you *can* do it, yes, ask yourself: *should* you do it, and can it be done quickly enough?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure here, but does NSManagedObjectContext retain its store coordinator and object model? In that case, wouldn't it suffice to have your controller retain the managed object context?